# Modify h5 file to fix error with Keras I/O

Tags: keras, theano, h5py

Few weeks ago, I trained a convolutional neural network (CNN) using Keras with Theano backend, and I saved it as a h5 file.

But today when I tried to open it, I got this error for the BatchNormalization layer, from Theano bn.py file:

> ValueError: epsilon must be at least 1e-5, got 9.99999974738e-06

So here are my questions:

1. Can I do something with Keras to fix this problem?
2. If the first question does not have an answer, how can I modify a h5 file in order to modify manually this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a temporary solution to this problem. The Theano file bn.py has two similar tests since the last version (around lines 220 and 380), and these tests are responsible of the problem:

```
if epsilon < 1e-5:
    raise ValueError("epsilon must be at least 1e-5, got %s" % str(epsilon))
```

A temporary solution would be to replace the raise by an affectation:

```
if epsilon < 1e-5:
   epsilon = 1e-5
```

It's not ideal, but it allows to read the old files. Do not forget to undo this modification afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my case for future reference because [duckduckgo.com](https://duckduckgo.com/) brought me here.

In my case, I did not have the same error as OP, but I had the same problem of having an h5 file that was trained and saved but wouldn't load because of [keras issue 2814](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2814): `TypeError: arg 5 (closure) must be tuple`. I ended up modifying temporarily the keras code in the lambda deserialization function [keras.layers.core.Lambda.from_config](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L699) from

```
    elif function_type == 'lambda':
        # Unsafe deserialization from bytecode
        function = func_load(config['function'], globs=globs)
```

to

```
    elif function_type == 'lambda':
        # Unsafe deserialization from bytecode
        if 'my_lambda_name' in config['function'][0]:
          print('bypassing lambda function')
          function = lambda x: x
        else:
          function = func_load(config['function'], globs=globs)
```

This bypasses the offending lambda function. It works for me because that specific lambda function in that specific h5 was just acting as `lambda x: x` eventhough it was a bit more complicated than that.

Then I wrote a small script that loaded the model and saved it in a new file (with the bypassed lambda layer)

```
from keras.models import load_model
print('fixing file')
model = load_model('path/to/file.h5')
model.save('path/to/file.fixed.h5')
print('fixed')
```